# Include indirect members in the Google App Script Vacation Calendar

Tags: google-apps-script, google-calendar-api

[Google's Vacation calendar script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/samples/automations/vacation-calendar) grabs vacation events from members of a Google Group e-mail address, but only direct members because it uses the line:

```
let users = GroupsApp.getGroupByEmail(GROUP_EMAIL).getUsers();
```

And `getUsers()` "[gets the **direct** members of the group...Note: if you are a member of a group B which is itself a member of another group A then you are indirectly subscribed to group A. Although you receive copies of messages sent to it, you are **not** actually subscribed to the parent group A](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/groups/group#getusers)".

So how to get both direct and indirect members of a group and implement it in the Google's vacation calendar code? Google's code is:

```
// MAKE A COPY. If you try to run this script before making a copy in your own account, it won't work.

// To learn how to use this script, refer to the documentation:
// https://developers.google.com/apps-script/samples/automations/vacation-calendar

/*
Copyright 2022 Google LLC

Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
You may obtain a copy of the License at

    https://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
limitations under the License.
*/

// Set the ID of the team calendar to add events to. You can find the calendar's
// ID on the settings page.
let TEAM_CALENDAR_ID = 'ENTER_TEAM_CALENDAR_ID_HERE';
// Set the email address of the Google Group that contains everyone in the team.
// Ensure the group has less than 500 members to avoid timeouts.
let GROUP_EMAIL = 'ENTER_GOOGLE_GROUP_EMAIL_HERE';

let KEYWORDS = ['vacation', 'ooo', 'out of office', 'offline'];
let MONTHS_IN_ADVANCE = 3;

/**
 * Sets up the script to run automatically every hour.
 */
function setup() {
  let triggers = ScriptApp.getProjectTriggers();
  if (triggers.length > 0) {
    throw new Error('Triggers are already setup.');
  }
  ScriptApp.newTrigger('sync').timeBased().everyHours(1).create();
  // Runs the first sync immediately.
  sync();
}

/**
 * Looks through the group members' public calendars and adds any
 * 'vacation' or 'out of office' events to the team calendar.
 */
function sync() {
  // Defines the calendar event date range to search.
  let today = new Date();
  let maxDate = new Date();
  maxDate.setMonth(maxDate.getMonth() + MONTHS_IN_ADVANCE);

  // Determines the time the the script was last run.
  let lastRun = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().getProperty('lastRun');
  lastRun = lastRun ? new Date(lastRun) : null;

  // Gets the list of users in the Google Group.
  let users = GroupsApp.getGroupByEmail(GROUP_EMAIL).getUsers();

  // For each user, finds events having one or more of the keywords in the event
  // summary in the specified date range. Imports each of those to the team
  // calendar.
  let count = 0;
  users.forEach(function(user) {
    let username = user.getEmail().split('@')[0];
    KEYWORDS.forEach(function(keyword) {
      let events = findEvents(user, keyword, today, maxDate, lastRun);
      events.forEach(function(event) {
        importEvent(username, event);
        count++;
      }); // End foreach event.
    }); // End foreach keyword.
  }); // End foreach user.

  PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().setProperty('lastRun', today);
  console.log('Imported ' + count + ' events');
}

/**
 * Imports the given event from the user's calendar into the shared team
 * calendar.
 * @param {string} username The team member that is attending the event.
 * @param {Calendar.Event} event The event to import.
 */
function importEvent(username, event) {
  event.summary = '[' + username + '] ' + event.summary;
  event.organizer = {
    id: TEAM_CALENDAR_ID,
  };
  event.attendees = [];
  console.log('Importing: %s', event.summary);
  try {
    Calendar.Events.import(event, TEAM_CALENDAR_ID);
  } catch (e) {
    console.error('Error attempting to import event: %s. Skipping.',
        e.toString());
  }
}

/**
 * In a given user's calendar, looks for occurrences of the given keyword
 * in events within the specified date range and returns any such events
 * found.
 * @param {Session.User} user The user to retrieve events for.
 * @param {string} keyword The keyword to look for.
 * @param {Date} start The starting date of the range to examine.
 * @param {Date} end The ending date of the range to examine.
 * @param {Date} optSince A date indicating the last time this script was run.
 * @return {Calendar.Event[]} An array of calendar events.
 */
function findEvents(user, keyword, start, end, optSince) {
  let params = {
    q: keyword,
    timeMin: formatDateAsRFC3339(start),
    timeMax: formatDateAsRFC3339(end),
    showDeleted: true,
  };
  if (optSince) {
    // This prevents the script from examining events that have not been
    // modified since the specified date (that is, the last time the
    // script was run).
    params.updatedMin = formatDateAsRFC3339(optSince);
  }
  let pageToken = null;
  let events = [];
  do {
    params.pageToken = pageToken;
    let response;
    try {
      response = Calendar.Events.list(user.getEmail(), params);
    } catch (e) {
      console.error('Error retriving events for %s, %s: %s; skipping',
          user, keyword, e.toString());
      continue;
    }
    events = events.concat(response.items.filter(function(item) {
      return shoudImportEvent(user, keyword, item);
    }));
    pageToken = response.nextPageToken;
  } while (pageToken);
  return events;
}

/**
 * Determines if the given event should be imported into the shared team
 * calendar.
 * @param {Session.User} user The user that is attending the event.
 * @param {string} keyword The keyword being searched for.
 * @param {Calendar.Event} event The event being considered.
 * @return {boolean} True if the event should be imported.
 */
function shoudImportEvent(user, keyword, event) {
  // Filters out events where the keyword did not appear in the summary
  // (that is, the keyword appeared in a different field, and are thus
  // is not likely to be relevant).
  if (event.summary.toLowerCase().indexOf(keyword) < 0) {
    return false;
  }
  if (!event.organizer || event.organizer.email == user.getEmail()) {
    // If the user is the creator of the event, always imports it.
    return true;
  }
  // Only imports events the user has accepted.
  if (!event.attendees) return false;
  let matching = event.attendees.filter(function(attendee) {
    return attendee.self;
  });
  return matching.length > 0 && matching[0].responseStatus == 'accepted';
}

/**
 * Returns an RFC3339 formated date String corresponding to the given
 * Date object.
 * @param {Date} date a Date.
 * @return {string} a formatted date string.
 */
function formatDateAsRFC3339(date) {
  return Utilities.formatDate(date, 'UTC', 'yyyy-MM-dd\'T\'HH:mm:ssZ');
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update:** I've combined both solutions into 1. If you find it useful, you should know Google [officially approved it](https://github.com/googleworkspace/apps-script-samples/pull/390) (you may want to ask them to add it to the article link).

So it seems it must be done recursively, i.e. using [getGroups](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/groups/group#getGroups()) to see which groups are inside other groups, and cleaning duplicated members, then doing it until no more groups inside groups are found.

An alternative is to just add support for manually specifying multiple groups.

So I've added:

```
let ONLY_DIRECT_MEMBERS = false;
```

Then replaced:

```
  let users = GroupsApp.getGroupByEmail(GROUP_EMAIL).getUsers();
```

with:

```
  if (ONLY_DIRECT_MEMBERS)
    let users = GroupsApp.getGroupByEmail(GROUP_EMAIL).getUsers();
  else if (Array.isArray(GROUP_EMAIL))
    let users = getUsersFromGroups(GROUP_EMAIL);
  else
    let users = getAllMembers(GROUP_EMAIL);
```

And added these function:

```
/**
* Get both direct and indirect members (and delete duplicates).
* @param {string} the e-mail address of the group.
* @return {object} direct and indirect members.
*/
function getAllMembers(groupEmail) {
  var group = GroupsApp.getGroupByEmail(groupEmail);
  var users = group.getUsers();
  var childGroups = group.getGroups();
  for (var i = 0; i < childGroups.length; i++) {
    var childGroup = childGroups[i];
    users = users.concat(getAllMembers(childGroup.getEmail()));
  }
  // Remove duplicate members
  var uniqueUsers = [];
  var userEmails = {};
  for (var i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
    var user = users[i];
    if (!userEmails[user.getEmail()]) {
      uniqueUsers.push(user);
      userEmails[user.getEmail()] = true;
    }
  }
  return uniqueUsers;
}

/**
* Get indirect members from multiple groups (and delete duplicates).
* @param {array} the e-mail addresses of multiple groups.
* @return {object} indirect members of multiple groups.
*/
function getUsersFromGroups(groupEmails) {
  let users = [];
  for (let groupEmail of groupEmails) {
    let groupUsers = GroupsApp.getGroupByEmail(groupEmail).getUsers();
    for (let user of groupUsers) {
      if (!users.some(u => u.getEmail() === user.getEmail())) {
        users.push(user);
      }
    }
  }
  return users;
}
```

If you like to grab users from multiple groups, then also replace:

```
let GROUP_EMAIL = 'ENTER_GOOGLE_GROUP_EMAIL_HERE';
```

with an array:

```
let GROUP_EMAIL = ['ENTER_GOOGLE_GROUP_EMAIL_HERE', 'ENTER_ANOTHER_GOOGLE_GROUP_EMAIL_HERE'];
```

Full version:

```
// To learn how to use this script, refer to the documentation:
// https://developers.google.com/apps-script/samples/automations/vacation-calendar

/*
Copyright 2022 Google LLC

Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
You may obtain a copy of the License at

    https://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
limitations under the License.
*/

// Set the ID of the team calendar to add events to. You can find the calendar's
// ID on the settings page.
let TEAM_CALENDAR_ID = 'ENTER_TEAM_CALENDAR_ID_HERE';
// Set the email address of the Google Group that contains everyone in the team.
// Ensure the group has less than 500 members to avoid timeouts.
// Change to an array in order to add indirect members frrm multiple groups, for example:
// let GROUP_EMAIL = ['ENTER_GOOGLE_GROUP_EMAIL_HERE', 'ENTER_ANOTHER_GOOGLE_GROUP_EMAIL_HERE'];
let GROUP_EMAIL = 'ENTER_GOOGLE_GROUP_EMAIL_HERE';

let ONLY_DIRECT_MEMBERS = false;

let KEYWORDS = ['vacation', 'ooo', 'out of office', 'offline'];
let MONTHS_IN_ADVANCE = 3;

/**
 * Sets up the script to run automatically every hour.
 */
function setup() {
  let triggers = ScriptApp.getProjectTriggers();
  if (triggers.length > 0) {
    throw new Error('Triggers are already setup.');
  }
  ScriptApp.newTrigger('sync').timeBased().everyHours(1).create();
  // Runs the first sync immediately.
  sync();
}

/**
 * Looks through the group members' public calendars and adds any
 * 'vacation' or 'out of office' events to the team calendar.
 */
function sync() {
  // Defines the calendar event date range to search.
  let today = new Date();
  let maxDate = new Date();
  maxDate.setMonth(maxDate.getMonth() + MONTHS_IN_ADVANCE);

  // Determines the time the the script was last run.
  let lastRun = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().getProperty('lastRun');
  lastRun = lastRun ? new Date(lastRun) : null;

  // Gets the list of users in the Google Group.
  if (ONLY_DIRECT_MEMBERS)
    let users = GroupsApp.getGroupByEmail(GROUP_EMAIL).getUsers();
  else if (Array.isArray(GROUP_EMAIL))
    let users = getUsersFromGroups(GROUP_EMAIL);
  else
    let users = getAllMembers(GROUP_EMAIL);

  // For each user, finds events having one or more of the keywords in the event
  // summary in the specified date range. Imports each of those to the team
  // calendar.
  let count = 0;
  users.forEach(function(user) {
    let username = user.getEmail().split('@')[0];
    KEYWORDS.forEach(function(keyword) {
      let events = findEvents(user, keyword, today, maxDate, lastRun);
      events.forEach(function(event) {
        importEvent(username, event);
        count++;
      }); // End foreach event.
    }); // End foreach keyword.
  }); // End foreach user.

  PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().setProperty('lastRun', today);
  console.log('Imported ' + count + ' events');
}

/**
 * Imports the given event from the user's calendar into the shared team
 * calendar.
 * @param {string} username The team member that is attending the event.
 * @param {Calendar.Event} event The event to import.
 */
function importEvent(username, event) {
  event.summary = '[' + username + '] ' + event.summary;
  event.organizer = {
    id: TEAM_CALENDAR_ID,
  };
  event.attendees = [];
  console.log('Importing: %s', event.summary);
  try {
    Calendar.Events.import(event, TEAM_CALENDAR_ID);
  } catch (e) {
    console.error('Error attempting to import event: %s. Skipping.',
        e.toString());
  }
}

/**
 * In a given user's calendar, looks for occurrences of the given keyword
 * in events within the specified date range and returns any such events
 * found.
 * @param {Session.User} user The user to retrieve events for.
 * @param {string} keyword The keyword to look for.
 * @param {Date} start The starting date of the range to examine.
 * @param {Date} end The ending date of the range to examine.
 * @param {Date} optSince A date indicating the last time this script was run.
 * @return {Calendar.Event[]} An array of calendar events.
 */
function findEvents(user, keyword, start, end, optSince) {
  let params = {
    q: keyword,
    timeMin: formatDateAsRFC3339(start),
    timeMax: formatDateAsRFC3339(end),
    showDeleted: true,
  };
  if (optSince) {
    // This prevents the script from examining events that have not been
    // modified since the specified date (that is, the last time the
    // script was run).
    params.updatedMin = formatDateAsRFC3339(optSince);
  }
  let pageToken = null;
  let events = [];
  do {
    params.pageToken = pageToken;
    let response;
    try {
      response = Calendar.Events.list(user.getEmail(), params);
    } catch (e) {
      console.error('Error retriving events for %s, %s: %s; skipping',
          user, keyword, e.toString());
      continue;
    }
    events = events.concat(response.items.filter(function(item) {
      return shouldImportEvent(user, keyword, item);
    }));
    pageToken = response.nextPageToken;
  } while (pageToken);
  return events;
}

/**
 * Determines if the given event should be imported into the shared team
 * calendar.
 * @param {Session.User} user The user that is attending the event.
 * @param {string} keyword The keyword being searched for.
 * @param {Calendar.Event} event The event being considered.
 * @return {boolean} True if the event should be imported.
 */
function shouldImportEvent(user, keyword, event) {
  // Filters out events where the keyword did not appear in the summary
  // (that is, the keyword appeared in a different field, and are thus
  // is not likely to be relevant).
  if (event.summary.toLowerCase().indexOf(keyword) < 0) {
    return false;
  }
  if (!event.organizer || event.organizer.email == user.getEmail()) {
    // If the user is the creator of the event, always imports it.
    return true;
  }
  // Only imports events the user has accepted.
  if (!event.attendees) return false;
  let matching = event.attendees.filter(function(attendee) {
    return attendee.self;
  });
  return matching.length > 0 && matching[0].responseStatus == 'accepted';
}

/**
 * Returns an RFC3339 formated date String corresponding to the given
 * Date object.
 * @param {Date} date a Date.
 * @return {string} a formatted date string.
 */
function formatDateAsRFC3339(date) {
  return Utilities.formatDate(date, 'UTC', 'yyyy-MM-dd\'T\'HH:mm:ssZ');
}

/**
* Get both direct and indirect members (and delete duplicates).
* @param {string} the e-mail address of the group.
* @return {object} direct and indirect members.
*/
function getAllMembers(groupEmail) {
  var group = GroupsApp.getGroupByEmail(groupEmail);
  var users = group.getUsers();
  var childGroups = group.getGroups();
  for (var i = 0; i < childGroups.length; i++) {
    var childGroup = childGroups[i];
    users = users.concat(getAllMembers(childGroup.getEmail()));
  }
  // Remove duplicate members
  var uniqueUsers = [];
  var userEmails = {};
  for (var i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
    var user = users[i];
    if (!userEmails[user.getEmail()]) {
      uniqueUsers.push(user);
      userEmails[user.getEmail()] = true;
    }
  }
  return uniqueUsers;
}

/**
* Get indirect members from multiple groups (and delete duplicates).
* @param {array} the e-mail addresses of multiple groups.
* @return {object} indirect members of multiple groups.
*/
function getUsersFromGroups(groupEmails) {
  let users = [];
  for (let groupEmail of groupEmails) {
    let groupUsers = GroupsApp.getGroupByEmail(groupEmail).getUsers();
    for (let user of groupUsers) {
      if (!users.some(u => u.getEmail() === user.getEmail())) {
        users.push(user);
      }
    }
  }
  return users;
}
```

Comment: I've combined the initial 2 solutions into 1.